# Setting up Gauss-Seidel Method

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

### Background

> 2. Solve the following set of nonlinear equations by the Gauss-Seidel method:
>
> $$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> 27x+e^x \cos\ y -0.12z & =\ 3, \\
> -0.2x^2+37y+3xz &=\ 6, \\
> x^2-0.2y \sin x+29z & =-4.
> \end{array}\right.$$
>
> $\quad $ Start with an initial guess of $x=y=z=1.$

I'm trying to implement Gauss-Seidel method in $C$ with the following set of equations. I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve for $x$. It is pretty straight forward to solve for y and solve for $x$. I would really be appreciative is someone knows a way to isolate $x$ so I can start iterating through. Thanks so much for any thoughts.

### My Understanding

This is what I have thus far:

From eqn 2)$$ y = \frac{(6-3xz+.2x^2)}{37} $$
From eqn 3)$$ z = \frac{-4+.2y\sin{x}-x^2}{29}$$
This is where I am stuck
$$ 27x + e^{x}\cos{y} = 3+.12z$$

Comment: Do you know the Gauss-Seidel method? Have you tried to apply it to the problem? If yes, did you encountered some problems? Please, let us know.

Comment: Yes. Also yes the problem is to apply that method to this system, which is why I am here asking details about how to do it. I cannot solve for x with any of the equations. I can solve for y and z.  I can't update x and thus continue iterations because I can't solve for it.

Comment: Well, can you post your efforts?

Comment: Sure! I have modified the original post to include this work, thanks for the help!

Comment: They want you to do is "solve the linear part" to set up Gauss-Seidel. So in the first equation $x=\frac{3+0.12z-e^x \cos(y)}{27}$ and so on. Then you iterate. "Conventional" fixed point iteration would do all these iterations at the same time, so $x_{n+1}=f(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ and same for the others; Gauss-Seidel has you immediately throw away the old value of each variable as you compute a new one, so for instance $x_{n+1}=f(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ but $y_{n+1}=f(x_{n+1},y_n,z_n)$.

Comment: Oh ok! So I get to use the old value of x on the RHS of that first eqn you wrote in order to update the new x on the LHS for that same equation?

Comment: That's right. Do you see why most likely the Jacobian matrix of the resulting iteration function will be relatively small, assuming, say, $x \leq 3$? (It has to do with the denominators...)

Comment: Ah, I am not quite there in my understanding to grasp the Jacobian matrix yet, just learned about this method today. When I coded up a simpler system of eqns in C using this method, I tracked the changes  in x_n -> x_n+1 through each iteration for all 3 dimensions just to see how they behaved. All 3 dx,dy,dz get smaller and smaller as it converges. I'm betting the jacobian probably implies that somehow? I so so appreciate the help, Ian and the_candyman. Thank you so much for spending your time to help me here. Very grateful! This is such a neat method, can't wait to learn more.